# android ndk /dev/input/event0 root permission

Tags: android, android-ndk, root

I have learn ndk developing in android platform.I'm confused how to get root permission when i read file"/dev/input/event0"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtfop.jpg)

Comment: Use real device instead of emulator & your device should be rooted super user.

Comment: @NovusMobile I'm using real device and the device is rooted